# webpack-bundle-analyzer is not working

Tags: angular, webpack, package.json, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I run below command to create stats.json:

> ng build --prod --stats-json

After this I am executing below code:

> webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json

once I execute it I am receiving below error in my terminal:

> 'webpack-bundle-analyzer' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

I have installed webpack-bundle-analyzer.

In Package.json file it's available

> "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1"

Please help me to resolve.

Note :  Stats.json is available in dist folder

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have `npm` >5.2 installed,   a new utility, [npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx) should already be available 
 Execute 
`npx webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json`

else you can add a new `npm script` that calls `webpack-bundle-analyzer` add this in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",

},
```

Execute `npm run stats`

Answer (score 2):

As commands should be added to the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) before it can be called from terminal/shell.
So after I try to install the package into global, I can use it:

```
npm i -g webpack-bundle-analyzer
```

I think by adding the directory you install the package locally to the `PATH` will fix the problem too.